# Access violation when writing an array value inside range

Tags: c, arrays, visual-c++, access-violation

I'm trying to initialize an array of 32-bit integers bu for some reason the debugger (MSVC) throws an exception halfway through the writing process.

The array is 1048576 elements long
Fails on iteration 263152

```
#define ROM_MAX_SIZE (1024*1024*4)
int main(){
    size_t rom_size = ROM_MAX_SIZE / sizeof(uint32_t);
    uint32_t *rom = malloc(rom_size); //<-- Error here, must be ROM_MAX_SIZE. See edit

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < rom_size; i++){
        rom[i] = i; //<--- Access violation here
    }
free(rom);
return 1
}
```

I might be missing something obvious but I don't see it.

---

Edit:

Malloc has to be 4 times the number of elements.

```
uint32_t *rom = malloc(rom_size); //<--- WRONG!
uint32_t *rom = malloc(ROM_MAX_SIZE); //<--- OK.
```

Comment: Why do you think it is in range?

Comment: Debugger fails when i==263152 *way* below the 1048576 array size. As stated in the post, juuust above the code.

Comment: Malloc is quarter size. must be ROM_MAX_SIZE not ROM_MAX_SIZE/4

Comment: Malloc allocates in bytes, not ints.

Comment: As Joe said - it allocates in bytes, Malloc has not to be 4 times the number of elements but "number of elements" x "size of one element". In your situation, size of uint32_t is 4.

Comment: I know. I noticed just after posting that I was passing malloc the element count instead of the array size in bytes. I typed rom_size (bad name for a var) instead of ROM_MAX_SIZE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allocate it like this

```
    uint32_t *rom = malloc(rom_size * sizeof(uint32_t));
```

in current situation, your array is four times smaller then you expected.

Comment: Just noticed that and edited it accordingly. Have the answer anyway.